# Cannot convert system.object[] to system.byte[], solutions and workarounds

Tags: vb.net

Trying to create a function to simplify ratios (stored as arrays of length 2, with the index 0 being the numerator and index 1 being the denominator). This function gives me an error when the values passed in are object attributes.

Here is the function:

```
Function SimplifyRatio(Numerator, Denominator)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim PNA() As Integer
    i = 0
    PNA = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199}

    While i < PNA.Length()
        If Numerator Mod PNA(i) = 0 And Denominator Mod PNA(i) = 0 Then
            Numerator = Numerator / PNA(i)
            Denominator = Denominator / PNA(i)
            i = 0
        End If
        i = i + 1
    End While
    Return {Numerator, Denominator}
End Function
```

And here is the method containing the erroneous function call:

```
Public Function CalculateRatio()
    Dim ratio(1) As Byte
    ratio = SimplifyRatio(Gear.Teeth, Pinion.Teeth)
    Return ratio
End Function
```

Any help would be appreciated,
Yours Sincerely,
KyuSiik

Comment: why dont you have types on the parameters and return type of the function?

Comment: I think a solution that is not simply a workaround but a *global fix*, is to set `Option Strict` and `Option Explicit` `On` by default. Correct all the errors/suggestions that squiggle up and you're (mostly) good.

Comment: Also, what is the Type of `Gear.Teeth` and `Pinion.Teeth`? `Integer` or `Byte`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. Gear.Teeth and Pinion.Teeth are both of type Byte. The return type of the function is an array of length two, also I forgot to set the return type of the function, thanks for reminding me (pls forgive me, I'm used to Python)

Comment: I'll also try the Option Explicit thing, that sounds like it might work, thanks for the help, all of you.

Comment: Then the method in the first code snippet is `Function SimplifyRatio(Numerator As Byte, Denominator As Byte) As Byte()`. Inside you have `Dim PNA() As Byte` and `Numerator = Numerator \ PNA(i)` (note the slash), the same for the next one. The method in the second snippet is `Public Function CalculateRatio() As Byte()`. Btw, Happy New Year!